# Need Form successful message

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form that I need to be able to have an error message display if the username and password are blank, or not long enough. I have figured this out and it is working. My problem now is 2 fold. #1 how can I get multiple errors to show in 1 alert? (use of an array??) and how do I produce a successful alert if all has been entered correctly. Here is my javascript and html.

```
<script>
function formIsValid(){
var validation = true;
validation &= checkUsername();
validation &= checkPassword();
return validation;
}   


function checkUsername(){
var name= document.forms["RegistrationForm"]["user"].value; 
var nameLength =name.length;
if(name == ""){
alert ("Please Enter a Username");
return false;
}
else if (nameLength <8){
alert ("The Username must be 8 characters");
return false;
}
}

function checkPassword(){   
var password=document.forms["RegistrationForm"]["pass"].value;
var passwordLength =password.length;
if(password ==""){
alert ("Please Enter a Password");
return false;
}
else if (passwordLength <8){
alert ("The Password must be 8 characters");
return false;
}
}



</script>
```

Html code

```
<form name="RegistrationForm"  onsubmit="return formIsValid()" action="">
<h2>Registration</h2>
Username:<input type="text" name="user" size="20"/> (At least 8 characters)<br/>
<br/>
Password:<input type="text" name="pass" size="20"/> (At least 8 Characters)<br/>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">    
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"/>
<p>
</form>
```

Comment: For your first question, you should pack all of your validation in a single function. In this function, you throw your validation function and instead of showing a single alert() for each errors, store them in an array and set a boolean to false. At the end of the verification, you throw an alert if your boolean is false and then your add your string error which have been stored in the array. 

For the second question, why do not simply display an alert() too ?

Comment: You could instead of using alert, put your error message in an array, then if your array is not empty, there's error(s) and you view them by looping through the errors.

Comment: See below code i added some validations here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code and it should work the way you want. :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var userFlag =true;
var passFlag = true;
var msg = "";
function formIsValid(){
  checkUsername();
  checkPassword();
  if(passFlag && userFlag ){

   return true;
  }
  else{
    alert (msg);
    msg="";
    return false;
  }
}   


function checkUsername(){
  var name= document.forms["RegistrationForm"]["user"].value; 
  var nameLength =name.length;
  if(name == ""){
    msg +="Please Enter a Username";
    userFlag = false;
  }
  else if (nameLength <8){
    msg +="The Username must be 8 characters";
    userFlag = false;  
  }
}

function checkPassword(){   
  var password=document.forms["RegistrationForm"]["pass"].value;
  var passwordLength =password.length;
  if(password ==""){ 
    msg += " and Please Enter a Password";
    passFlag = false;
  }
  else if (passwordLength <8){
    msg += "and The Password must be 8 characters";
    passFlag = false;
  }
}
</script> 
</head>

<body>
    <form name="RegistrationForm"  onsubmit="return formIsValid()" action="">
      <h2>Registration</h2>
      Username:<input type="text" name="user" size="20"/> (At least 8 characters)<br/>
      <br/>
      Password:<input type="text" name="pass" size="20"/> (At least 8 Characters)<br/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"/>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works on multiple alerts, however there is no message if it is successful at the end. If it creates a error message then after you fix it you get the success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something a little like this:

```
function checkPassword(errors){   
    ...
    if (password == "") {
        errors.push("Please Enter a Password");
    } else if (passwordLength <8){
        errors.push("The Password must be 8 characters");
    }

    return errors;
}
```

Then your calling method could look like this:

```
function formIsValid(){
    var errors = [];
    errors = checkUsername(errors);
    errors = checkPassword(errors);

    if (errors.length == 0) alert('win');
    else alert(errors.join('\r\n'));
}
```